# Rollback state of Stateful session bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

Does transaction rollback affects Stateful bean state ?
For example : if Exception occure's during JMS message handling, does injected Stateful bean will refresh it's state ?

**update**

There is an option to implement SessionSynchronization interface and afterCompletion method that allows to refresh state of the bean.
But the question is - can it be done in automated way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on exception type, container discards bean instance (such that you can't reference to it again) on rollback due to RuntimeException and keeps bean state after Rollback for ordinary exception.